# github pull request automatic merge

Tags: git, github

Recently I have come across a very unusual case where github created redundant merge commit apart from the usual "Merge pull request #XXX"

The redundant one has a mask: "Merge branch 'feature branch' of github.com:myorg/myrepo into master"

What's more, this commit is present in both feature branch and master branch.

And the most interesting part is the master graph:
[image]

What happens in 1 is of a great mystery to me.

Can someone elucidate?

Comment: In 1 your branch diverges to commit 2 and commit 3

Comment: Why does it diverge? Both commits are merge commits(created automatically).